# TypeError: Error #1009 in button Click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting errors like

```
   TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at home_fla::MainTimeline/frame4()[home_fla.MainTimeline::frame4:14]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at home_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame4()[home_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:26]
```

when I tried to button click from frame 1 to page4 - name of fourth frame.

```
settingsBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame4);
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(settingsBtn);
    gotoAndStop("page4");
}
```

Since I'm new to AS3, I couldn't find solution for this by my own. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not enough code, but here's a tip that could help you - if you start Flash with debugger SHIFT+CTRL+Enter (Command for Mac) your debugger will likely pinpoint a null reference object. Basically it means that it's calling some method/property of an object that is null

Comment: @Jojo George Why don't you show as the code on frame4

Answer (score -2):

I guess the `frame4` object (referenced by "page4") is `null` at the time you call `gotoAndStop("page4")`.

Comment: `page4` is a string literal in this context, it can't be null.

Comment: page4 is just a label of a frame. It can't be null, even if there's no such frame the error is different. Most probably on frame labeled page4 there is some call to a null object.

Comment: @MartyWallace but it refers to a frame which is an object

Comment: @CreativeMagic I suppose you are right. You are the Flash pro! ;-) I'm mainly on Flex, where it's a common mistake to refer to an component (e.g. on another tab) when it's not instanciated.